# Space Complexity of an array?

Tags: java, space-complexity

I have an array of size N, and N is <=200.

What would be the space complexity here.

**O(1)** or **(N)** - considering the constraint N.

Comment: its just N isn't it?

Comment: Isn't the space-complexity relevant for algorithms ? What is your algorithm ? Given N, create an array of size N ? It's O(N). If it's inside another algorithm with an input of size n (independant of N) and you just need to create an Array of size N, it's O(1).

Comment: @nafas yeah i thought the same. But N is not growing here, it's constant.

Comment: @JeremyGrand yeah it makes sense.

Comment: @Ritesh N is still a variable. its not a constant

Comment: @nafas yeah, but it's constrained to 200.

Comment: @Ritesh variable is still a variable, u know Integer is also restricted to 2^31 , 200 is pretty much the same

Comment: @nafas yeah. i agree. i think in this case, if the array size is fixed and its not growing in anywhere, the complexity should be O(1).

Comment: @Ritesh that's right, say if N was always equal to 200, then its constant and O(1) . I know its a bit  silly, but that's precisely the distinction between constant and variable

Comment: Actually, if I remember my math class from 10 years ago, once N < 200, O(N) and O(1) are the exact same thing. see my answer for precision.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Complexity is only relevant when you try to foresee the performances of your algorithm with various input. I don't think it has any meaning to just speak about the space-complexity of an array without any context.

If you'll always create an array of size N (hard-coded), it's **O(1)**, because no matter what input your algorithm crunches, the space taken by your array is the same.

If your N grows with the size of the input, it's **O(f(n))**, where f(n) is the relation between n (size of input) and N (size of array).

NOTE : the formulation O(...) is a mathematical symbol to represent magnitude without any regard to the multiplier (sorry for the lack of precision, I'm way over my math degree and never learned the english terms), so, if N is a constant, **O(N) = O(1)** (they have the exact same meaning).

And if I'm remembering it right, if *f* < C * *g* , O(f) = O(g). Thus, if N is < 200 , O(N) = O(200) = O(1)

Comment: I personally don't think this is true. the constant value K = 200, but N is variable, it can be small, or large (N < K constraint). Imagine K = 2^10000.... Would it still be O(1) because "there's a constant constraint?" No, right?, because N can be 0..2^10000, so the space it takes depends on the value of N, and it follows a linear pattern. Thus O(N)

Comment: mate , I don't think its right, say in java Max Integer = 2^31 -1 , can you still consider N <= Max(Integer) to have O(1)? if its the case O(N) is completely irrelevant to anything

Comment: Yeah, I was speaking on a mathematical standpoint. The thing is that in computing n (as the size of the input) is necessarily bounded. So, we actually need to look whether K is meaningful against n.

Comment: You are right about the context though: If you make a function `createArray(N){ return new Array(K) }`, then yes, the space complexity of your code will be O(1). But `createArray(N){ return new Array(N) }` is O(N)

Comment: @olivarra1 this is why a sufficiently large constraint (anything on the order of 2^wordsize) is usually ignored, but technically it works that way

Comment: @olivarra1 I guess OP's issue is that N grows with n (input size) but is bouded by 200 as a mean to forcibly prevent this part of the algorithm to take too much resources, which means when n is small enough, the array is O(n), but when n is big, it becomes O(1). I guess that's a O(1)

Comment: @JeremyGrand when we're constraining N we're just saying "let's suppose we won't ever get beyond that". N > 200, where it would hipotetically be O(1) will never happen (what hapens if N = 300 while the array created is of length 200 because of O(1)? Looks glitchy!)

Answer (score 7):

Space complexity is usually only defined for Algorithms.

But let's be *crafty* and form an algorithm from your Question.

```
Input: N values, N <= 200
Algorithm: Store all values
Output: None
```

Space complexity is the amount of memory you need to execute the algorithm, in relation to N.

When you store 1 number, you'll need one memory area. When you store 2 it doubles...
Your memory complexity is **O(n)** which means it grows linearly; Just like it would be for this algorithm:

```
Input: N values, N <= 18,446,744,073,709,551,616 (unsigned int 64).
Algorithm: Store all values
Output: None
```

**But 200 is a really small number, can't we just say O(1)?**

Let's get crafty again, because we can make this O(1):

```
Input: N values, N <= 200
Algorithm: Store all values in an array of size 200
Output: None
```

When you store 1 number you will need 200 memory areas. When you store 2 numbers you will need 200 memory areas. When you store 200 numbers you will need 200 memory areas. This means the memory is constant and independent from N. Thus the complexity is O(1).

It's important to note that O(1) doesn't mean the amount of memory you need is 1, it means that the amount of memory you need is not in any relation to N. And thus it doesn't grow when N grows.

**But what if my objects are 50GB Blu-ray Discs?  O(1) should be very small but now it would be 10 Terabytes!**

At this point we may finally realize that we don't always need to use Big O notations. We could just say that we need to store 10 Terabyte of Data and buy some Hard Disks.
If your Teacher makes a fuss about whether you write O(1) for very small N or O(n), then he is a very bad teacher. The answer to this Question is neither going to change your life nor your career. *Big O Notation only makes sense for numbers that can grow incredible large.*

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the case of your problem.if you use only constant amount of memory (or space). So, space complexity is **O(1)**.

However, if you have some data structures like a 1D-array, designed to hold N elements, where N can vary from input-to-input, then the amount of memory required is dependent on N. When N is small, the space required is also small. When N is large, then space required is also large. So, there is a linear dependence on the space required and the input size. That is **O(N)** space.

Similarly, if you have a 2D-array of size NxN, then generally, the space required is **O(N^2)**.

Consider the following example of finding the minimum space required for the algorithm:

```
 Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
 int n = in.nextInt();
 int[] array = new int[n];
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
     array[i] = in.nextInt();
 }
 int minimum = array[0];
 for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
     if (array[i] < minimum){
        minimum = array[i];
     }
 }
 System.out.println(minimum);
```

Here, we are having an array, whose size varies with `n`. Total space requirement = `2 + N`, where `2` is for the variables `n` and `minimum` and `N` is for the `array`. So, the space complexity of this algorithm is **O(N)**.

I hope this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be O(1).space complexity is O(n) if the space size increase linearly with increase of n.But in your case the function is not dependent on n after 200;
f(n)=a*n+b..

Answer (score 1):

> I have an array of size N, and N is <= 200.

Ok, you have an array of size N. What about it? meaning, having some data stored does not have any meaning in terms of space complexity since there is no context like some code (algorithm) that uses this array (space). So you can't measure space complexity of nothing (no code to be run, just data sitting there).

Now, if you use this array in some context like a function that creates N times this input array where N <= length of this array, then you can measure how space grows in relation to run time (time spent for a number of statements/lines executed) of this function.

> What would be the space complexity here.
>
> O(1) or (N) - considering the constraint N?

In your case, space complexity would be O(1) because there is no grows in run time since there is no code to be executed. just one piece of data (your array).

I hope this helps